# Regex stop match immediatlly or if there is a comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I probably didn't phrase the question in the best way, but bear with me

Having this string

```
select * from my_functions (in_p1 := remove,
                                   in_p2 := $1,
                                   in_p3 := remove,
                                   in_p4 := $2,
                                   in_p5 := remove,
                                   in_p6 := $3,
                                   in_p7 := remove)
```

I need to remove the parameters that are matched for retrieval, with the `remove` keyword

So I built this `text = text.replace(/,[^,]*?remove/g, '')`, which works for every case except `p1`. How can I tell it to stop the match immediattly or if there's a comma, to only stop after the comma ?

Comment: Can you rely on the `in_` prefix in those names?

Comment: No, sometimes they don't have the prefix

Comment: It might be easy to tell for us humans, but how does the computer know that it shouldn't match the entirety of `select * from my_functions (in_p1 := remove`? Are the parameters, for example, all composed of `[A-Za-z0-9_]`?

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9_]` I think we can assume it yes

Comment: That will cause `,,`

Comment: Okay, this seems to work nicely. Thanks :) Add it as the answer if u wish

Comment: I just realised what I said won't work... Sorry!

Comment: Dont worry I will go with @T.J.Crowder answer, thanks for ur troubles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to remove the comma in two possible places, the only option I see for doing this with a single regex is an alternation:

```
//                   vvvvvvvvvvvvv−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− first alternative
text = text.replace(/,[^,]*?remove|(?<=\()[^,]*?remove,/g, '');
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−− second alternative
```

The alternatives are your original expression that matches things other than `in_p1`, and an alternative that matches `in_p1` and removes the comma after it (rather than in front of it).

Example:

```js
let text = `select * from my_functions (in_p1 := remove,
                                   in_p2 := $1,
                                   in_p3 := remove,
                                   in_p4 := $2,
                                   in_p5 := remove,
                                   in_p5_ := remove,
                                   in_p6 := $3,
                                   in_p7 := remove)`;
                                   
text = text.replace(/,[^,]*?remove|(?<=\()[^,]*?remove,/g, '');
console.log(text);
```

Note that that uses a lookbehind for the `(`. Lookbehind is relatively new to JavaScript. I think we can get rid of the lookbehind if your target platform doesn't support it by using a capture:

```
text = text.replace(/,[^,]*?remove|(\()[^,]*?remove,/g, '$1');
```

Example:

```js
let text = `select * from my_functions (in_p1 := remove,
                                   in_p2 := $1,
                                   in_p3 := remove,
                                   in_p4 := $2,
                                   in_p5 := remove,
                                   in_p5_ := remove,
                                   in_p6 := $3,
                                   in_p7 := remove)`;
                                   
text = text.replace(/,[^,]*?remove|(\()[^,]*?remove,/g, '$1');
console.log(text);
```

---

Note that I added an extra parameter in there just to double-check that two "remove" parameters in a row were removed correctly.

Comment: *(If you don't see an alternative [no pun!] avoiding the lookbehind, hit refresh. I added one.)*

Comment: *(There also wasn't any reason for having the non-capturing group, that was an editing error. I've removed it.)*

Comment: I went with the first one, going to read about the lookbehind now. Thanks man!

Comment: @Greggz - My pleasure. There's a support matrix [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Basically, they're supported on modern browsers other than Safari, but it's still fairly new. (Safari will undoubtedly add support at some point.) Legacy Edge (v44 and earlier, which is still the current Edge for a large number of people as the Chromium Edge rollout is incremental) and IE don't support them.